# Samba share activation under windows

Tags: windows, archlinux, samba

I try to connect my Sambashare with my Windows Pc. The Sambashare is on my arch linux server in the home network and I tried it with a second os on my pc(I have dualboot), and it worked. The second is on my pc Fedora Linux.

I was expecting, that because it worked the second time in Fedora it also has to work in Windows, but I was wrong. I also tried it with another pc in the network and it doesn't work (also Windows). I don't know if I should try and if the mistake is in the server or then I try to connect to Windows.

Now, an explanation of what I do when I try to connect Arch with Windows:

For connecting the Sambashare with Windows, I go to Windows in the file explorer, click on my pc and click at the top on connect network drive. Then I use the ip to connect, I exactly type this: `smb://192.168.2.109/sambashare`. Last but not least I make sure that all boxes under the address are checked. I click on finish and a warning pops up. In the pop-up stands windows couldn't find the share. (I also shut everything down and up, before I tried it)

Comment: try superuser.com